# Removing "i" from the triangle inequality?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, triangle-inequality

In my complex analysis class, I have to prove that a limit exists for a function and I think I can use the Triangle Inequality in my proof, but I don't know if it's possible. My question: knowing that $|a| + |b| \le |a + b|$, am I allowed to then say $|a| + |b| \le |a + ib|$? I saw someone do it in their own proof, but I'm a bit skeptical mostly because I don't quite understand. Thanks!

Comment: The inequality you assert is false $|1+(-1)|=0$ but $|1|+|-1|=2$ (you have the Triangle Inequality backwards).

Comment: Ekorel, actually it results that $|a+b|\leqslant|a|+|b|$ and this inequality holds not only for all real numbers, but also for all complex numbers $a$, $b$.

Comment: Using the comments of lulu and Angelo, you can say that $~|a + ib| \leq |a| + |ib| = |a| + |b|.~$  Note that for complex numbers $~z_1,z_2~$ you have that $|z_1 \times z_2| = |z_1| \times |z_2|.~$  This explains why $~|b| = |ib|.~$

Comment: god, i've just been getting everything wrong today. ugh. thank you all for your help.

Comment: @user2661923 Post as an answer?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Can't, as absurd as it sounds, because the OP's (i.e. original poster's) posted question is defective, with respect to [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).  More important to observe the protocol than to register the question as answered.  In my judgement, the OP was confused by the comparison of $~|b|~$ with $~|ib|, ~$ and lulu and angelo had already posted their comments, so I took an incremental step forward, to get the OP thinking.   ...see next comment

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Personally, I regard the whole idea of giving priority to a high quality repository over education as daffy.  If it were up to me, I would therefore answer just about every question posted.  However MathSE doesn't belong to me, so I follow the will of the majority.

Comment: @user2661923 Those are good (i.e., accurate) points. Admittedly, (i) I remain in _prefer-answers-to-protocol_ mode; (ii) the Rules at MSE, such as they are, baffle me (to the slight extent I try to follow arguments back and forth); (iii) it may be a matter of time before I get smacked for this.